# How do I fix this run-on sentence?

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis, run-on-sentence

How would I fix the bolded sentence to not be a run-on sentence? It says what I want it to, but I would like a better structure or choice of words.

> While I studied at ABC Community College I worked a full-time job in order to support myself. Though the work was rewarding and necessary, it limited my ability to focus on my school work.  Even though I was able to work with my professors to extend deadlines and make up missed work, my work responsibilities limited my ability to complete assignments and prepare for exams. **When I transferred to XYZ College I learned to better manage my time and adapted my life to balance work and school.**  I was able to finish my undergrad with a much higher GPA, even though I continued to work full-time.

Comment: That's not a "run-on sentence", which is school-marm talk for joining independent clauses without either a conjunction or a 'disjunctive' point (full stop, colon, semi-colon, or dash). Your sentence does not have two independent clauses but two predicates joined with the conjuction *and* ; consequently, the school-marm will not whack you.

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB stated, the sentence in question is not a run-on sentence. It's perfectly valid as it is, and requires no fixing. As Ralph Jin suggested, you may be able to make it flow better if you add a comma after "XYZ College"; however, this is not required. It simply depends whether you want to imply a short pause at that point or continuing on without one. In this case, it would probably be easier to say out loud with a pause, so you might prefer that. The same could be applied earlier in the paragraph after "ABC Community College," where you have a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this run-on sentence, you just need to add a comma after the XYZ College. A quick way to fix run-on sentences in the future is to read the sentence to yourself and see how you would change the sentence if this was a conversation.